# Is it possible to have input from one device populate one field in tkinter, and another device that populates a different field?

Tags: python, tkinter, serial-port, usb, stdin

I have a keyboard and a USB bar scanner and two separate monitors at different locations all connected to the same computer.
I want the keyboard to enter data on one monitor, and the scanner to enter data on the other monitor.
Is there a way to take data from, say, COM3 and use it for an Entry box on monitor 1, and take the data from COM4 and use it for an Entry box on monitor 2?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can create a `Toplevel` window that is visible the same time as the root `Tk()` window and send data to `Entry`s in either one of them from any source.

Comment: The problem is: how do I determine which source goes to which window.  I need only the keyboard to go to window 1 and only the scanner to go to window 2.

Comment: Seems like if you know the source of the data — which you should — then that alone would be enough information to determine which `Entry` to send it to.

Comment: I'm obviously missing something here.  I don't see how knowing where the data comes from helps me direct it to where it needs to go.  The entering of data on monitor 1 (keyboard) might happen at same time as the entering of data on monitor 2 (scanner).  At monitor 1, the fields are selected by mouse click.  There will be no mouse or keyboard at monitor 2, and maybe not even an actual Entry box.  I just bind '<Key>' to the window and programmatically grab the data from stdIn.  That is why I need to know which USB port the data is coming from.

Comment: For data to be coming in concurrently from different devices, you will need to set up some background thread(s) that monitor the device(s) and when data is received they put it in a Queue that the main thread running the GUI periodically checks and updates the proper `Entry`s or `Text` widgets as needed. It has to be done this way because `tkinter` doesn't support multithreading in the sense that only one thread in a multithreaded application can access it. Periodic polling of the Queue is usually handled via the universal `after()` widget method. There are many question here on the topic.